# Android: App Icon as Up Button does not work

Tags: android, button, menu, icons

iam following the basic beginner Tutorial on the Android Developer Site. Now, i there is described how to bring the app icon as the Up Button (see last text): http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav

I put "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" in my activitys onCreate() Methods, but on my Device my App has no App Icon as the Button. Here are my activities

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

and

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

And also my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.andreas.myapplication.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

And Gradle Infos

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.andreas.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

iam confused because im alredy use the right method for minSdkVersion 8.

Does anyone know, why ma App does not show the Icon as Up-Button?

best Regards

Comment: I guess that `MainActivity` should not show an UP button, since it's already the TOP LEVEL Activity. But `DisplayMessageActivity` should.

Comment: Yes it should not. But this is not a question about should or not should of the existence of the up button. It should show the app icon, and the app icon is not shown in the TOPLevel or in the DisplayMessageActivity eather.

Comment: If it shouldn't, the you can remove this line in MainActivity: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. And the part where you create the TextView at run time and set it as the ContentView... looks at least naive, to my eyes.

Comment: Of course its naive. Its the beginning Tutorial of the Android Developer site as described it here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

the problem is, that it should show my icon with getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); but it does not, like its described in the end

Comment: Well, I don't find a reference to setting a TextView as a content View in that link... Apart of this, I'd use Fragments (1 activity and as many Fragments as needed). So, I would use the standard up arrow, which is system managed "out of the box" with no other tricks.

Comment: this is made here

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

however, i try another tutorial for the home things. Seems the better solution but thanks anyway

Comment: No, well, certainly doable, but... quite uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem - enabling "display home as up" led to the Up button with an arrow image on it. I have managed to replace arrow with an app icon with the following steps:

- Create a new `ImageAsset` with app icon images in `/drawable`.
- In `OnCreate()` of child activity, add 2 lines:

  ```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);                    
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_home);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Substitute meta-data value     **android:value="com.example.andreas.myapplication.MainActivity"**  for  **android:value=".MainActivity"**

To support older devices with the support library, also include a element that specifies the parent activity as the value for android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY as shown below:

```
<!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
<meta-data
     android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
     android:value=".MainActivity" />
```

[A full explanation is here: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-add-up-button-on-action-bar/](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-add-up-button-on-action-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` after calling `setContentView(textView);` in the second activity.

**EDIT:**

also, main activity should not call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` as it leads nowhere. And you should add a button to switch activities or you will never get to DisplayMessageActivity. try something like this:

```
Intent showmessg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(showmessg);
```

Hope it works for you.

source: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it does not help. Does not change anything. And this is just the "child activity". In the main activity, the Up Button as an Icon does not shown too.

the Intent i have in my code, but not in the onCreate method i show here. The Problem is only the Icon nothing else, but thanks.

Comment: the app starts in the activity with the <intent-filter>, so you need a way to get tho the child class. read the edit.

Comment: i go to my child over my "send button". I have there the intent

Comment: /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); // EditText bei ID finden
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent); // Startet eine Instanz einer Aktivität die im Intent definiert ist, siehe new Aufruf
    }

Comment: just move the getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); to after setContentView(textView); and let me know what happens.

Comment: Nothing happens. Everything like before

Comment: so to be clear: in the second activity you cant push the icon to go back. that is the problem.

Comment: no. the problem is not that the up button does not work. the problem is that my up button is not an icon like here: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-up.png  it is just text, but it should be the icon from my application.  This is what the Tutorial said "Then enable the app icon as the Up button by calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled():"

Comment: Do you have a app icon? (the default does not show on appcompact themes)

Comment: are you sure its not shown? cant believe that. Whatever, ive copyd the "ic_launcher"-icons item from all folders, named it appicon, put it back, change in the manifest the icon from ic_launcher to appicon, but this changed nothing. still no icon on the bar with getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); here the icon is shown in the bar. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: appcompact never shows icon for me, just have to use other theme

Answer (score 0):

I think in android 5 and API 21 we can't use app icon for up action.
if your appcompat support library is v7 rev21 i think you can't use the app icon at least for up action. but u can use it instead of top left caret or you can use app icon right of that caret although if u click it nothing happen.

I have two app completely like that  trainings in one of them i use the older appcompat v7 and minSdkVersion="11" and i never added `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
 to it but app have app icon and no problem . but in another app i update my support library a few day ago to rev21 and of course this app's minSdkVersion is "8" but this app hasn't actionBar icon for Up action and if you add top code to it you do nothing.
I search many of sites and just i understand is that in material design google removed app icon for up action because of increasing space on actionbar and etc. 
You can see this line in [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html).

> "When using the Material themes (default in API 21 or newer) the
>   navigation button (formerly "Home") takes over the space previously
>   occupied by the application icon. Apps wishing to express a stronger
>   branding should use their brand colors heavily in the action bar and
>   other application chrome or use a in place of their standard title
>   text."